# near "SET": syntax error , while trying to set isolation level

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm, transaction-isolation

I want to create a transaction in go and while doing that I get error : `near "SET": syntax error`. The code:

```
db.Exec("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;")
if err := db.Exec("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED").Error; err != nil {
    return err
}

tx:=db.Begin()
```

Even when omitting ";" I get the same error. I'm using sqlite3 database and gorm ORM.

Comment: That's not valid sqlite dialect sql. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this in SQLite you have to use [pragmas](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html).

Does this work?

```golang
if err := db.Exec("PRAGMA read_uncommitted = true").Error; err != nil {
    return err
}

tx:=db.Begin()
```